# Libinput but timer offset negativ on Arch linux with wayland

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, wayland

Sometimes firefox is freezing my laptop. When i open webpages like [this one](http://www.debugpoint.com/libreoffice-basic-macro-tutorial-index/)  or [this one here](http://www.spox.com/de/sport/ussport/nba/index.html?gr=www). The number of pages which are capable of freezing firefox increases.

The log reveals a buch of messages like this one:

```
Nov 23 19:19:45 name org.gnome.Shell.desktop[438]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer event6 trackpoint: offset negative (- xyz)
```

Google showed that some people have the same problem but no real solution.
I hope someone can help me.

I use Arch linux. With wayland 1.14.0